# Customise commitlint header format

Tags: git, githooks, husky, commitlint

I am using Husky to set my git hooks, and am trying to change to default format of the header expected by [Commitlint](https://commitlint.js.org):

```
type(scope?): subject
```

I am specifically trying to have this formatting:

```
:gitmoji:? [scope] subject
```

With `:gitmoji:` one of [Gitmoji](https://gitmoji.dev/)'s emoji and being optional, with square brackets around the scope (and not optional) instead of the parentheses, and without the `:` to separate the type + the scope from the subject. Also I'd like the `scope` to have a formatting kind of like `TCKT-666` (to refer a Jira's ticket, for example),

Right now, I've been trying a lot of things using the `parserPreset`, `parserOpts`, `headerPattern` and `headerCorrespondence` properties from `commitlint.config.js`, but I encountered several issues:

- the `headerPattern` regex seems to be totally ignored, and all the errors I get only come from the rules I set within `commitlint.config.js` - so I cannot set a specific formatting for my `scope` (although [commitlint-plugin-function-rules](https://github.com/vidavidorra/commitlint-plugin-function-rules) might help with that)
- I have absolutely no idea how to remove the need for the `:` after the type, or how to replace parentheses by square brackets around the scope

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :/

Comment: I have a POC, will answer maybe tomorrow with a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for `:gitmoji:? [scope] subject`

```js
module.exports = {
  parserPreset: {
    parserOpts: {
      headerPattern: /^(?:(:\w+:)\s)?\[(\w+)\] (.+)/,
      headerCorrespondence: ["type", "scope", "subject"],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      rules: {
        "header-match-team-pattern": (parsed) => {
          const { type, scope, subject } = parsed;
          if (type === null && scope === null && subject === null) {
            return [
              false,
              "header must be in format ':gitmoji:? [scope] subject'",
            ];
          }
          return [true, ""];
        },
        "gitmoji-type-enum": (parsed, _when, expectedValue) => {
          const { type } = parsed;
          if (type && !expectedValue.includes(type)) {
            return [
              false,
              `type must be one of ${expectedValue}
    see https://gitmoji.dev`,
            ];
          }
          return [true, ""];
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  rules: {
    // "type-empty": [2, "never"],
    "header-match-team-pattern": [2, "always"],
    "gitmoji-type-enum": [2, "always", [":bug:", ":sparkle:"]], // custom rule defined in plugins
    // "subject-case": [2, "always", "sentence-case"],
  },
};
```

---

Looks like it's required to have a custom rule like `header-match-team-pattern` that makes sure that RegExp matched.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that as soon as I'm done with my current task ^^

Comment: I haven't been able to use the `explained-type-enum` rule, and I don't find any corresponding rule or plugin in https://commitlint.js.org/#/reference-rules or on npm. Is there a package you used to make that work?

Comment: I assume the custom rule `explained-type-enum` is the one that should be definable in the plugins? (I didn't find anything related to that in the docs)
Also I tried several things such as `git commit -m ":yahahalalala: [ Something else entirely"` and `git commit -m "[ Something else entirely"` and they were not blocked by commitlint for some reason...

Comment: After a little research, I found that your solution may not work because of an issue with headerPattern that is yet to be resolved: https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/issues/607

Comment: I updated the answer, see if it's working for your use cases!

Comment: It's totally working now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it support typescript? Can you include kind of JIRA tickets format?